# vector.at() chokes despite index being well under capacity

Tags: c++, std, stdvector

I am developing a C++ application using CodeBlocks 10.05 under Debian 7.0.0.

I allocate space to a vector thus.

```
std::vector<double> dpMeanUnnormalizedRef;
dpMeanUnnormalizedRef.reserve(expectedUpperLimit);
```

I then try to add a value.  Unfortunately the indices where I need to add values are not sequential so I cannot use push.  The first time I try to add an element the call is as follows.

```
dpMeanUnnormalizedRef.at(index)=doubleVar;
```

at this point, has a size of 0, a capacity of 621 while index has a value of 0.  Yet this call causes the program to throw an out of range exception.

Comment: Perhaps you want `std::map<int,double>` instead. That way you can add only the indices you want to.

Comment: "Index under capacity"? In order for `at` to work, the index has to be under *size*, not under *capacity*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`reserve` simply reserves the physical space for the items without actually adding them to the vector. It is intended to enhance efficiency by reducing the number of reallocations when you know how large the vector will be ahead of time. You need to use `resize`.

Answer (score 2):

As Mark says, `reserve` only helps `vector` manage its memory, it does not actually add elements, you can use `assign`

Instead of

```
dpMeanUnnormalizedRef.reserve(expectedUpperLimit);
```

Use

```
dpMeanUnnormalizedRef.assign(expectedUpperLimit,0.0);
```

You can also use `resize` or the constructor itself.